# Trying to add a second player on Skylanders Swapforce Wii U

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

Is it possible to play with two players on Skylanders' Swapforce with the game pad and one controller? It says to press A to add a controller by pressing A doesn't do anything. Thanks.